# How to create UI from code?

Tags: android, xamarin

I tried to add some controls dynamicaly from code, not from .xml. I used code like:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            mainLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainLayout);

            Button test = new Button(Window.Context) { Text = "BLABLABLA" };
            test.SetWidth(100);
            test.SetHeight(100);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams _params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 0.0f);
            _params.SetMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
            mainLayout.AddView(test, _params);
        }
```

But button does not appear in my application. What can be wrong?

UPDATE: Now it works! But I don't understand what I did and why it had not run before. But anyway thank you all.

Comment: can you show your `Resource.Layout.Main` as well?

Answer (score 1):

You miss the call `setContentView(mainLayout);` within your `onCreate()` method.

Note that you have to call this method **after** generating your layout.

Comment: I don't miss the call. And I tried to set text in diffirent ways. I didn't help

Comment: @user2140182 You have to call it after generating your layout

Answer (score 0):

First of all to set the LayoutParams you should set it to the Button test and not the layout like this:

```
test.setLayoutParams(_params);
```

and then to add it to the mail layout, like this:

```
mainLayout.AddView(test);
```